# How to make a communication web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm a HS student learning web dev and I am trying to build a basic helpdesk using ruby on rails. As of now, it consists of a basic CRUD system which puts the users questions into a database along with an email address so I can respond. My question is:

How would I go about making a web app that allows me to respond to the question in the webpage itself?

Comment: You're able to store something (email) in the database. So, what exactly is the problem with storing something else (the response) in the database?

Comment: wouldnt that make my database abnormally large?

Comment: Define "normally". Also, your entire question is vague. It's not clear at all what you want to do.

Comment: what im trying to do is add functionality that will allow a user to send a message to the admin and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You need some sort of event pipeline, and a way to publish messages back to the webpage.

The crudest way to do this would be a timer in javascript that checks for new messages every x milliseconds and then appends these to the DOM of the messaging element on your html page.

A far better solution in Rails would be [ActionCable](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) - [here's a basic tutorial](https://gorails.com/episodes/rails-5-actioncable-websockets)